# TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '...'

Tags: typescript

```
interface BaseRelationBoxLogicState {
    settingsMenuAnchorEl: null | HTMLElement;
    showSettingsMenu: boolean,
}
interface BaseRelationBoxLogicProps<T extends BaseRelationBoxLogicState> {
    SpecializedRelationBoxLogic: (props: T) => JSX.Element;
}
class BaseRelationBoxLogic<T> extends Component<BaseRelationBoxLogicProps<T>, BaseRelationBoxLogicState> {
                          ^^^  <--- ERROR:  TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'BaseRelationBoxLogicState'.
    state = {
        settingsMenuAnchorEl: null,
        showSettingsMenu: false,
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting an error in the above code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `BaseRelationBoxLogicProps` type requires that it's `T` parameter extends `BaseRelationBoxLogicState` when it's declared like this:

```
interface BaseRelationBoxLogicProps<T extends BaseRelationBoxLogicState> {
//                                    ^ constraint
```

However, when you declare the `BaseRelationBoxLogic` class the generic parameter `T` has no requirements. It could be anything.

```
class BaseRelationBoxLogic<T>
//                         ^ no constraint
```

So If you plan on forwarding a generic parameter to another type, then you need to constrain that type to something that the downstream type will accept.

In this case, you need to repeat your generic constraint:

```
class BaseRelationBoxLogic<T extends BaseRelationBoxLogicState> extends 
    Component<BaseRelationBoxLogicProps<T>, BaseRelationBoxLogicState>
{
  //...
}
```